# google map plugin on wordpress page not showing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps

I have a website made with Wordpress that should show a Google Map on three sub-pages. The problem is the map only shows if I open the page and then refresh it.

Note: I don't have a cache plugin installed.

[Live site](http://sasa2017.ch/trauung/)

[Google Maps plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-maps/)

Comment: i now tried it with another plugin for google maps but this also doesn't work. i guess the theme is somehow interrupting with the maps plugin. anyone out there who can help?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved now.
it was an issue with the theme. i deactivated the ajax of the theme and the maps are now working.